# bm-bookmarks show bookmarks on closed buffers

Tags: bookmarks

I use the **bm package**.  Is there any way to go to a saved bookmark while the file where it was defined is closed (means not opened in a active buffer). While using :

> bookmark-set, bookmark-jump, bookmark-save

I can go to a saved bookmark with **C-x r b** even it the file is not opened in a buffer.  Can we do the same with bm ?

Answer (score 0):

I am no bm user, but quickly looking at it, it looks like it is able to save all markers, but for some reason does not provide an option to show all saved markers (so the markers only 'become available' after visiting some previous buffer). If you'd like to have that functionality, I would advise you to open an issue at [bm](https://github.com/joodland/bm).

On the other hand, it looks like [desktop.el provides functionality for persistent evil marks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41383/26163)
(and as mentioned already [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74407/how-to-configure-initial-evil-state-for-major-mode), those marks can be made visible also).

Finally, there is [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) which should be able to do all of this also, but I guess for evil users the previous mentioned solution is preferable.